# I cannot see the option-'Azure resource group deployment'

Tags: azure-devops

I am going to Release my Pipeline from dev_env to product_env.  so i am going with release option. but in the task function.. i cannot see the 'azure resource group deploy' option

so give me information about this

How can i release my pipeline

Comment: Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answer can give you some help

Answer (score 0):

> i am going with release option. but in the task function.. i cannot see the 'azure resource group deploy' option

Based on your requirement, you are finding the azure resource group deploy task in Release Pipeline. Refer to this doc: [AzureResourceGroupDeployment@2 - Azure resource group deployment v2 task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-resource-group-deployment-v2?view=azure-pipelines)

To meet your requirement, you can refer to the following steps:

Step1: Search and find the task: **ARM template deployment** task. By default, it will use  version 3.

[image]

Step2: You can select the Task version 2, then you will see the Azure resource group deployment task.

For example:

[image]